# Conditions for measurability on subspace of a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, banach-spaces

Assume that $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a probability space, and $E$ a separable Banach space, and let $f \colon \Omega \to E$ be a random variable with values in $E$. This implies that $f$ be measurable from $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ to $(E,\mathcal{B}(E))$, where $\mathcal{B}(E)$ is the Borel $\sigma$ field associated with $E$.

If $V \subset E$ is a subspace of $E$, under which conditions is $f$ also a $V$-valued random variable?

Thanks

Comment: Sure, I have removed it.

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: I proved that $f$ is an $E$-valued random variable. Now, I have also proved that, for almost all $\omega \in \Omega$, $f(\omega)$ is in $V \subset E$. Can I immediately conclude that $f$ is measurable from $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ to $(V,\mathcal{B}(V))$?  Is this trivial? Do I have a trivial result to quote

Comment: $V$ is a linear subspace of $E$? Then it is measurable in $E$. Any idea how can you express a measurable subset of $V$ via measurable subsets of $E$?

Comment: Also, if $f\in V$ only a.s. then you can only guarantee that a version of $f$ is a $V$-valued random variable, since for the latter we need that its image is a subset of $V$

Comment: @Ilya I am not sure I understand. Of course $f$ is measurable in $E$. I want it here to be measurable on $V$, with the Borel $sigma$ field of the smaller space, $B(V)$, not $B(E)$.

Comment: Can you answer my two questions?

Comment: @Ilya, thanks for your help. The setup I have in mind is $E=C([-1,1])$, with norm $\| \cdot \|_\infty$, and $V = C^1([-1,1])$, with norm $\| u \|_{C^1} = \| u \|_\infty + \| u’\|_\infty$. (This my answer to iquestion 2). I am stuck here (this is question 1, I hope)

Comment: Cool. Let’s say $B$ is a measurable subset of $V$. Is it a measurable subset of $E$?

Comment: Hi @Ilya I would say yes, via an inclusion mapping $i \colon V \to E$, hence $\| i(v) \| \leq \| u \|_V$ in the case above

Comment: Do you have measurability of $f$ then?

Comment: @Ilya do not know for sure, because the details of this calculation escape me.

Comment: What’s the definition of measurability?

Comment: @Ilya this starts to seem condescending. If I tell you I am stuck there, it’s because I can’t work it out from the definition of measurability myself. Maybe it looks trivial to you

Comment: Definition of measurability requires $f^-1(B) \in \mathcal F$ for every measurable $B$. You know that $f$ is $E$-measurable, so that holds for every $B\in \mathcal B(E)$. And since every measurable subset of $E$ is a measurable subset of $V$ per comments above, the same holds for every $B\in \mathcal B(V)$.

Comment: Thanks @Ilya, the argument you guided me to find, and completed above, would then be a proof of the following: If $V$ is continuously embedded subspace in a Banach space $E$, and $f \Omega \to E$ is measurable, then so is the restriction of $f$ to V. But where have we used separability? Is this a necessary requirement? Is this a standard result to be found in a book?

Comment: I’d say it is yes. Separability is nowhere needed.